# FocusEffect from default xamarin forms example not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need some help with effects for xamarin forms. I followed their webpage 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/creating/

and created a project to try to learn effects but I do not see any effects being implemented after implementing everything and I am not sure why. Would any kind soul be able to help me out with this?

Below is my code:

Under PCL project, I created a FocusEffect.cs file

```
namespace ShadowEffect
{
    public class FocusEffect:RoutingEffect
    {

        public FocusEffect() : base ("MyCompany.corp")
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Under UWP, I created a FocusEffect.cs file

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany.corp")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(FocusEffect), "FocusEffect")]

namespace ShadowEffect.UWP
{
    public class FocusEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                (Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                (Control as FormsTextBox).BackgroundFocusBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Under IOS, I created a FocusEffect.cs file

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany.corp")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(FocusEffect), "FocusEffect")]

namespace ShadowEffect.iOS
{
    public class FocusEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        UIColor backgroundColor;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                Control.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(204, 153, 255);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(args);

            try
            {
                if (args.PropertyName == "IsFocused")
                {
                    if (Control.BackgroundColor == backgroundColor)
                    {
                        Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Control.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Under Android, I have also created a FocusEffect.cs file

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany.corp")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(FocusEffect), "FocusEffect")]
namespace ShadowEffect.Droid
{
    public class FocusEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        Android.Graphics.Color backgroundColor;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                backgroundColor = Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen;
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(args);
            try
            {
                if (args.PropertyName == "IsFocused")
                {
                    if (((Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable)Control.Background).Color == backgroundColor)
                    {
                        Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Control.SetBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

and finally under the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShadowEffect"
             x:Class="ShadowEffect.MainPage">
             <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Entry Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Entry Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" >
            <Entry.Effects>
                <local:FocusEffect></local:FocusEffect>
            </Entry.Effects>
        </Entry>
        <Entry Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, the key inside the `RoutineEffect` constructor is inaccurate, preventing your effect from being called. It should be composed of the `ResolutionGroupName` key (in your case `"MyCompany.corp"`), `.` and the `ExportEffect` key (in your case `"FocusEffect"`) ([doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/creating#consuming-the-effect-in-xaml)).

Instead of hardcoded string, I would advise you to create a `static class Constant` with a `const` field `resolutionGroupName` to avoid typing mistakes and to define the `[assembly: ResolutionGroupName(Constant.resolutionGroupName)]` inside the `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

That said, try `"MyCompany.corp.FocusEffect"` in the `RoutineEffect` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the project compiled, I had an effect which cannot be found in my XAML files.

The error suggested me to build all assemblies, but even a clean/rebuild did not make it work.

What I simply did is closing/reopening my Visual Studio, and the effect was proposed by Intellisense in my XAML files.